# User interface freezes on Ubuntu 21.04 when using touchscreen on dock

Tags: crash, touchscreen, dock

I have installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop. When I use the touchscreen to open an application from the dock, there is a chance that the dock just freezes. It doesn't function anymore. Sometimes I try to press on an icon and it acts like I would press on another icon, sometimes it does nothing. And other GUI features of GNOME also act similar.

Why is this? And is there any permanent fix? I can fix the issue by rebooting or by restarting GNOME Shell.

My laptop is a HP Spectre x360. It has intel Iris Plus graphics.

Comment: I am running 21.04 on an HP Spectre x360, and I do not have this problem. A few years ago, there was a bug *similar* to what you describe, but it was fixed. (See [On touch screens, the apps icon in the dock does not open when touched](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1725384) and [Two instances of a program launch whenever you touch a favorites icon, or app grid won't show](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1745888)). Which HP Spectre x360 do you have? Are you running XOrg or Wayland?

Comment: One more question: are you able to open the app grid by clicking on the app-grid icon in the dock?

Comment: @PJSingh My spectre model is HP Spectre x360 13-aw0009nn. I run Wayland. And the apps sometimes open, other times they do that strange behaviour. Once that strange behaviour happens, I can't open any more apps. I have to reboot/restart GNOME. But from what I tested now, I can open the app-grid icon, and it seems that it doesn't crash/freeze

Comment: Try logging into an XOrg session instead of a Wayland session. (Although on XOrg, I am [unable to activate the app-grid button via touch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1940596), but everything else works).

Comment: @PJSingh I switched to XOrg and now everything works. Even the app grid. There still is a small issue: I now can't scroll using the touchscreen on firefox. And this was happening also on Ubuntu 20.04. But I'll try to also find a solution for this. Thx for the suggestion!

Comment: Regarding scrolling in Firefox, the only option is to try and (accurately) touch the scroll bar at the right, and slide that up and down.

Comment: I have the same issue on a DELL XPS laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in Wayland. Switching to X-Org is not a valid workaround for me. However, I'm curious about the reasons of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around is to log into the XOrg session instead of Wayland.

1. On the GDM Login screen, select your user ID.
2. Click the cog icon at
   the bottom right and select "Ubuntu on Xorg".
3. Then, enter your password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.